# Lost Win7 boot after installing UBUNTU Vivid

Tags: ubuntu, mount, windows, dual-boot, ntfs

I have a dual boot system (Win7 for my company) and (UBUNTU 14.10) .. My company is using Encryption for the image of Win7.
After Win7 installation i installed UBUNTU 14.10 and i was able to boot both.
My HDD is partitioned as follows:
3 Primary partitions (c: for windows , D: , E: for data ) and 5 Logical partitions (3 data and 1 for Ubuntu and 1 for swap).

Firstly, (N.B. Problem_1) I noticed that from Ubuntu i'm unable to mount any of the primary partitions, but i can normally mount the other logical ones.

Secondly, (N.B. Problem_2) I decided to test Ubuntu Vivid 15.04 so i installed it on one of the logical partitions.
After the installation i lost the Windows totally and i'm unable to boot to it, and from both Ubuntu versions, i'm unable to mount the primary partitions (ERROR: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,   missing codepage or helper program, or other error )
I used Boot Repair software on both Ubuntu versions, but none of them detected the Windows.

During boot of Ubuntu Vivid, it shows error (TPM error) and I understood that it is related to TPM Chip that is implemented for the security on Bios, i logged in to BIOS and disabled TPM option then the error disappeared.

I'm currently unable to boot from windows as it is not seen by Grub. And unable to mount the NTFS partition for windows.

If i understand well, this could be related to the security option done by the company that is preventing accessing the primary partition if the HDD is used outside the laptop, but at least i should be able to mount it even as Read-only or to boot from it in parallel with other OSs especially that it was working before and that i also disabled TPM.

Can anyone explain to me how to mount windows7 partition or to get its boot option back ?